# How to get from AlexNet multiple image labels

Tags: image, matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision

So, I am doing my Master's Thesis on the influence of super-resolution algorithms on the accuracy rate of image labeling by AlexNet. I am using Matlab with the pre-trained version of AlexNet.

The problem is that, by using

```
[label, scores] = classify(net, 'image')
```

I only get one label, whereas I would like to get multiple labels, e.g., five, and their corresponding scores by AlexNet.

I do not know how to do it and would really be very thankful if anyone could give me, at least, a hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `scores` matrix tells you how each class scored when classifying the data.  Specifically, each column `i` tells you how the score of the `i`th class faired when trying to classifying the input with class `i`.  Each row is one input into AlexNet.

If you want to get the top `k` scores for each input, you can [`sort`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) - specifically look at the second output variable and sort each row individually.  After, you can extract out the first `k` columns of the result which tells you the top 5 classes or labels that were associated with the input.  If you're concerned about the actual classes, look at the first output.

```
% First classify the image(s) you would like
[label, scores] = classify(net, ...);

k = 5; % We want 5 classes
[scores_sorted, classes] = sort(scores, 2); % Sort each row individually
scores_sorted = scores_sorted(:, 1 : k);
classes = classes(:, 1 : k);
```

`scores_sorted` and `classes` will now give you `k` column matrices where each row tells you the top `k` classes assigned for each input (stored in `classes`) as well as the scores provided by AlexNet (`scores_sorted`).

To finally determine what the actual classes are, when you create AlexNet, the final layer has the categories of classification. Assuming that you created the default net:

```
net = alexnet;
```

... you can determine what the classes are for each label ID by:

```
c = net.Layers(end).ClassNames;
```

This is a cell array of classes, and there should be 1000 elements in total. Therefore, given the classes variable from the code I wrote above, you can thus do:

```
out = net.Layers(end).ClassNames(classes);
```

`classes` would thus be used to index into the cell array and it will thus will give you a `N x k` cell array where each row in this cell array tells you the labels assigned by AlexNet for the top `k` classes per input image.

Comment: Wow, that was quick, thanks you so much :)) I understand that the score matrix is associated with the different classes, but I do not know how. Do they correlate in some way to the list of 1000 classes (or synsets) of the pre-trained AlexNet? Is there a way to map classes to scores?

Comment: `classes` will give you an integer index which you can use to index into the actual categorical data provided by AlexNet.  For example, if AlexNet assigned the output as class 400, this means that it belongs to whatever is category 400, assuming that you used the ILSVRC2010 data.  Mapping classes to scores is already done for you.  `scores` gives you the scores assigned for AlexNet while `classes` gives you how each class assigned the input the corresponding score.

Comment: The thing is, when using matlab's `classify` function, I only get 1 label (i.e., one class or synset), but I don't know how to get more of them. You seem to immply that I can get a variable called `class`, where all classes will be defined according to ILSVRC2010, but I don't know how to do it. I I would really appreciate it if you could tell me how to do it in matlab.  Thank you, really, very much for wanting to help me :)

Comment: I already told you how.  But if you really want me to go into detail, this is beyond the original scope of your question.  When you create AlexNet, the final layer has the categories of classification.  Assuming that you created the default net: `net = alexnet;`, you can determine what the classes are for each label ID by: `c = net.Layers(end).ClassNames;`.  This is a cell array of classes, and there should be 1000 elements in total.  Therefore, given the `classes` variable from the code I wrote above, you can thus do: `out = net.Layers(end).ClassNames(classes);` (continued below).

Comment: `classes` would thus be used to index into the cell array and it will thus will give you a `N x k` cell array where each row in this cell array tells you the labels assigned by AlexNet for the top `k` classes per input image.

Comment: Ok, I understand, I must use your code on my `score` result from `classify`. Thank you really very much :)

Comment: @JOSEMANUELRAMIREZLEON Correct!  You're very welcome.  Let me know if you need any more help and if you don't, please consider accepting the answer to let the community know you no longer need help in this regard.  Good luck!